# I would like to clarify how arguments pass(by value, referance) in erlang. I can't find material in which this topic discussed clearly

Tags: erlang

If I have a function which takes as argument list(or array), and then call that function recursively e.g

```
calculate_something(Arr) -> calculate_something(Arr, C),
calculate_something(Arr, C) -> do some stuff until some condition,
                            calculate_something(Arr, C).
```

I would like to clarify after every call calculate_something(...),  new list(or array) will be allocated as argument with the size of initial list(array) and increase memory stack or only reference of initial list(array) will be passed as an argument ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In effect, `Arr` acts as a reference. There's no need to make a new copy of it for each recursive invocation of `calculate_something/2` because `Arr` cannot be changed and is thus always bound to the same value for each invocation. Also, `calculate_something/2` as shown is tail recursive — there are no instructions following the recursive call at the end of the function, so even if each recursive call passed a new value instead of `Arr`, there'd be no reason to keep `Arr` around after that invocation because it's no longer needed once the next recursive call occurs.

See [the recursion chapter](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion) of [*Learn You Some Erlang For Great Good!*](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) for more information.